# Is it possible to delete messages in group chat through Line Messaging API?

Tags: chatbot, line-api

I want to create chatbot with Line Messaging API?

Main goal of chatbot is maintaining messages. I want to have only few people allowed to send messages and any other should be removed and these users should get private messages about that. Is it possible to achieve it in Line Chat App? Anyone had experience with similar task?

Messaging API I'm talking about, but maybe there are other solutions for my problem.
https://developers.line.biz/en/docs/messaging-api/overview/#what-you-can-do